# Multiple word replacement by list - duplicates creation

Tags: python, regex, list, replace, tcl

There is list of replacements ( http://pastebin.com/JH932Qxi ) 
and list which is necessary to replace ( http://pastebin.com/RSwdWiKy ).
Rules for replacement:

```
S1000005    =   S1000005,S1000006,S1000010
S1000007    =   S1000007,S1000008
S1000009    =   S1000009
S2000005    =   S2000005,S2000006,S2000007,S2000008
S2000009    =   S2000009,S2000010
S3000005    =   S3000005,S3000010
S3000006    =   S3000006,S3000008
S3000007    =   S3000007,S3000009
```

Input lines:

```
S1000005    S2000005    S3000005
S1000006    S2000006    S3000006
S1000007    S2000007    S3000007
S1000008    S2000008    S3000008
S1000009    S2000009    S3000009
S1000010    S2000010    S3000010
```

Result should be like this http://pastebin.com/8BkRFC87.

Example output:

```
S1000005    S2000005    S3000005
S1000005    S2000005    S3000006
S1000007    S2000005    S3000007
S1000007    S2000005    S3000006
S1000009    S2000009    S3000007
S1000005    S2000009    S3000005
```

I have done this using notepad++ (it saved time a lot), but it is possible to make fully automated. (At first I make splitting to the lines, than using bookmarks line replacement and than making 3 columns back).

How to read the list of replacements to create the replacement discretionary? And how to use dictionary to make lists of duplicates by replacement?

Or is there any text editor which can do search "S1000005,S1000006,S1000010,S1000011,S1000022,S1000023,S1000024,S1000025,S1000056" and replace each by "S1000005"?

Comment: Please show what you have tried and explain what did not work. Create a small example of what you need without all the external links.

Comment: Which language are you looking to use? You wouldn't ever use a mix of Python and Tcl for this sort of thing; that would be absurdly convoluted!

Comment: @DonalFellows I prefer Python or TCL.

Comment: @ChrisP What I have tried - multiple word replacement in the notepad++c-there is no option, only line replacement using bookmarks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the dictionnary {to be replaced: substitute} from the first file:

```
replace = {}
with open('input1') as fd:
    for line in fd:
        head, tail = line.split('=')
        for idt in tail.split(','):
            replace[idt] = head
```

write in `output` the content of the second file `input2`, with replacements:

```
with open('input2') as ifd, open('output', 'w') as ofd:
    for line in ifd:
        ofd.write('    '.join(replace.get(idt, idt) for idt in line.split()))
```

Here, the [dict.get](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method is used for take the identifier replacement, or the identifier itself if its not existing in the dictionnary.

In the vim text editor, the regex for replace `S1000005,S1000006,S1000010,S1000011,S1000022,S1000023,S1000024,S1000025,S1000056` by `S1000005` is:

```
%s/S1000005\|S1000006\|S1000010\|S1000011\|S1000022\|S1000023\|S1000024\|S1000025\|S1000056/S1000005/g
```

Under others text editors, some characters could need an escaping `\`. Depends of the used regex engine.
Other regex engine could accept this one:

```
s/{S1000005,S1000006,S1000010,S1000011,S1000022,S1000023,S1000024,S1000025,S1000056}/S1000005/g
```

Comment: Substitution in vim editor is fast and elegant solution. But I will try to make python code working.

Comment: Using this code generates 2 types of error: TypeError: expected a character buffer object (Pythin 2.7) and TypeError: write() argument must be str, not generator (3.5).

Comment: sorry for the typo, i forgot the `.join`. Fixed now.

Comment: Some replacements are not working, please, compare my hand-made output http://pastebin.com/8BkRFC87 and from this code http://pastebin.com/K01cNGVm the last element in lines is not replaced

Comment: OK, it is necessary to add ',' to the end of lines